# Does a leader have any other responsibility other than replication in Raft, like load balancing?

Tags: raft

We are trying to implement Raft in a chat application. As far as I read, Raft is for replication and thats it. So when a client wants to connect to the chat server for chatting with another client, does Raft require that all the clients connect to the leader only? If yes, if it connects to a follower, the follower can redirect it to the leader. But then what? Does the leader again assign it to a follower node i.e. essentially does the leader behave as a load balancer as well or does it do all the work itself with replication of users data on all other servers?

Comment: Hi there! The stackoverflow community enjoys helping out developers achieve their goals, with the premise of helping one's self first. In that regard, have a look at this [link][1] to help you better formulate your question, show your work and help us help you in general. Thanks! [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If the followers tell the clients the address of the current leader and the clients must re-connect to the leader, then the leader gets overloaded. The problem is that the leader is already doing the computation for the log replication and *all* the client processing also happens on the leader while the other nodes are practically idle. Furthermore, this severely limits the number of client connections you have.

If on the other hand, the followers accept the client connections and forward the requests to the leader (via a long-lived tcp connection), it forms a sort of connection fan-out that eases the load on the leader. The more processing you can do on the followers the better.

Extending upon the above, I have found success in making a few nodes invisible to the clients and these nodes have preference in being the leader. That way, they are *never* encumbered by client processing.

Comment: How does it reduce load on the leader to introduce an intermediate node that simply forwards to the leader? It's the same number of requests going to the leader. If you can service requests at following nodes only, without forwarding, then sure, but in general this is not the case. You would need to augment the answer to include this detail, with the caveat that your reads are no longer linearizable.